# I want to get the last email from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like

```
<?php
$string = "
hello aaa@aaa.com , you are the best.
this email bbb@bbb.com my be fake
(i have question to ccc@ccc.com)
that's all";
?>
```

I want to detect the last email (what ever number of email equal any number) for example: ccc@ccc.com

Comment: Interesting. I want to learn French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    function getLastEmail($_String)
    {
        $_RegVariables = "/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i";

        if (preg_match_all($_RegVariables, $_String, $_Matches))
        {
            $_Result = array();
            $_RegResult = array_combine($_Matches[0], $_Matches[0]);

            foreach($_RegResult as $key=>$value)
            {
                $_Result[] = $key;
            }
        }

        return $_Result[ sizeOf( $_Result )-1 ];
    }

    $string = "
hello aaa@aaa.com , you are the best.
this email bbb@bbb.com my be fake
(i have question to ccc@ccc.com)
that's all";

    $lastemail = getLastEmail($string);

    echo $lastemail;
?>
```

Now `$lastemail` is `ccc@ccc.com`

Good luck.

Comment: Beware that finding a regex that matches all email addresses is no easy task; a good article about this can be found in [Linux Magazine](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585).

Comment: +1 eykanal, I totally agree with you. Very hard to match em all. Especially with all the "new" TLD being added.

Comment: Thanks Cybrix, Dutchie432 .. this function is OK

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution, you may have to do some string clean up to remove characters (like '(' or ')') but this works if those aren't present.

```
<?php
$string = "
hello aaa@aaa.com , you are the best.
this email bbb@bbb.com my be fake
i have question to ccc@ccc.com 
that's all";

$a = explode(' ', $string);

$aEmail = array();
foreach($a as $svar=>$sval)
{ 
  if(preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $a[$svar]))
    $aEmail[] .= $a[$svar];
}


$sEmail_Last = array_pop($aEmail);
echo $sEmail_Last; // echo ccc@ccc.com

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas Kreidberg .. But with another string there is no output.